# How to remove "safeArea" appearance on the small screens in Swift? (Background is not on a full screen)

Tags: swift, uikit, uiscenedelegate

I'm making a project and fighting with the problem with the black borders - I can't understand why my background is not on a full screen. It seems like the anchors are right, maybe the problem is in SceneDelegate, but I don't know exactly.

Here is my SceneDelegate code:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    self.window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = DetailsViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

And here is my ViewController:

```
private let detailsView = DetailsView() // view where backgroundImage and cat picture exist

private func setupLayout() { // method for setting constraints for view
    view.addSubview(detailsView)
    detailsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    detailsView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

If you know how to fix this problem, please share with me. I tried to Google it but failed.

[Here is screenshot with the problem in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDMBZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi, do you need `detailsView ` appear full screen?

Comment: @SamB Hi! Yes, I need to display it without that black borders, on full screen

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constraints as below to make `detailsView` full screen. Here we are setting top,bottom,trailing and leading anchors of the `detailsView` to equal to those of `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`

```
private func setupLayout() { // method for setting constraints for view
    view.addSubview(detailsView)
    let safeAreaGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        detailsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.bottomAnchor),
        detailsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.topAnchor),
        detailsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.trailingAnchor),
        detailsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaGuide.leadingAnchor)
    ])
}
```